# How to create webgrid or table for my data

Tags: javascript, html

***This is my html codes***

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label style="text-align:left">Cari Kod:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="cariKod" value="" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <label style="text-align:left">Cari İsim:</label></td>
    <td><textarea rows="4" id="cariAd" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label style="text-align:left">Adres:</label></td>
    <td><textarea rows="4" id="Adress" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <td><button id="btn1" />Okey</td>
</table>
```

***This is my jquery codes***

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myform input').on('change', function () {
    $("#btn1").click(function () {
      var sonuc = ($("#cariKod").val() + $("#cariAd").val() + $("#Adress").val());
      console.log(sonuc);
    })
  })
});
</script>
```

***ı want to do a table or webgrid for my data input help pls.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <fieldset>
                    <table id="dinamiktablo">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div id="tableResult"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

    tr += "<tr>";



 tr += "<td>" + $("#cariKod").val() + "</td>"
                        tr += "<td>" + $("#cariAd").val() + "</td>"
                        tr += "<td>" + $("#Adress").val() + "</td>"
                        tr += "</tr>";
                        $("#dinamiktablo").append(tr)
```

***its fixed***

Answer (score 0):

You must to write something like this

HTML

```
<div id="tableResult"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT - JQUERY

```
var table = "<table>",
tableEnd = "</table>"

    $("#btn1").click(function () {
          table += "<tr><td>"+$("#cariKod").val() + "</td></tr>"
          table += "<tr><td>"+$("#cariAd").val() + "</td></tr>"
          table += "<tr><td>"+$("#Adress").val() + "</td></tr>"
          table += tableEnd;

          $("#tableResult").html(table)
    })
```

Comment: there is no error , not show any code in my console .